# Adding a Visio DataGraphic to a shape in C#

Tags: visio

I need to add the flags icon set DataGraphic to a Visio 2010 shape using C#.  I'm working with an embedded Visio Drawing Control and this all has to be done via code.

I'm having a lot of difficulty with this, and my usual strategy of using Macro-Recorder in Visio itself doesn't work here (I think it may be because this functionality is provided by an Add-In).

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Jeff

Answer (score 0):

See [About Displaying Data Graphically (Visio)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff766215.aspx).